# How does Scala get type safety on f String Interpolation

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

How does Scala get type safety on the f method String interpolation. The StringContext.f method takes args of Any. So how is it able to tell whether an Int, Double etc are required:

def f(args: Any*): String

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method `f` is implemented as [macro](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html).

In compile time macro implementation is called. Here is the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/reflect/MacroImplementations.scala#L14) or implementation.

Method `f` is defined as `def f(args: Any*): String`, but macro implementation can get actual parameters types (as `args: List[Tree]`) and actual string content.